# Extending Internet Explorer to use a credit card machine and cash drawer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a software application which is currently a win forms application using an embedded IE web browser control. The win forms application provides access to an attached credit card machine and cash drawer to the web site running in the IE web control. Its does this by creating JavaScript objects in the IE web browser control which the web applications calls to do operations such as perform a credit card swipe or open a cash drawer. Those js objects are mapped to methods in the win forms application which then interacts with the devices. Its a pretty cool solution except that the embedded IE web control lacks all of the great development tools of a standard web browser window. So...

I want to move the web application to being used in a normal web browser window (sticking with IE is fine for this client) while still having access to the credit card machine and the cash drawer. So my question is this... What solution is best or even possible?

- Active X Control - I do not really like this option
- Java Applet
- Flash
- Create an IE Extension - with an IE extension is it possible to do something like we are doing with our current solution? - Preferred option if possible

Does anyone have any experience with this or any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: why IE? Do you need to be in a browser for some reason?

Comment: Yes, we need to be a in a browser...  We could look at options other than IE...  I just need a way to connect a web app to external devices such as a cash drawer or credit card machine.  We already have working solution but it makes web development hard so we are looking for a way to enhance a browser instead of enhancing our app with browser, if that makes sense...

Comment: The browser could just make a ajax callback to a local service that works against the hardware. Though at that point, there's little benefit to go along with the absurd risks in putting it in the browser.

Comment: The web application is an intranet application accessed by 100 retail stores.  An ajax call would call the server and be of little benefit for accessing devices connected to a local machine in a store.  Our current solution is very secure except we lack access to modern web browser developer tools by using an embedded web browser control.

Comment: Not seeing why this needs to be browser based.  Sounds like it should have been a full, non hybrid desktop app from the beginning.

Comment: The web is a great way to go for any application which can run in a web browser...  Even a point-of-sale system...  Updates to the application are very easy to do and the system works great.  When it was originally coded years and years ago browsers did not really have the great developer tools they do now.  So we were not missing out on anything but now we are so we would like to keep it on the web but solve the problem of connecting to device.

Comment: @EricW.Greene you get into *significant* issues when you try doing a point of sale system and handling payment cards.  I would *strongly* suggest that you review the [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3.pdf) requirements.  In particular sections 1, 4, 5, 6.5, and Appendix A... though don't skimp on any of them.  There's things in this design that are making me feel uneasy about the design itself and exposing the CDE to potential attacks.  A POS system over the web just feels like a wrong design.  There are better approaches to application updates than webapps.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelT, I will take a look at the document you linked to.  Unfortunately, this is a huge existing legacy system.  Replacing it with something else is way above my pay grade.  Nevertheless, I will read what you have suggested and look for ways to make sure our solution is as secure as possible.  Thank you for taking the time to share your thoughts.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @EricW.Greene Its something you should pass up the chain and point out.  The PCI DSS isn't exactly 'optional' as its the Data Security Standards set up by Visa, MasterCard and the like as the requirements for companies that process payment cards. Bad Things happen to companies that don't follow those standards and suffer from a data breach that would have been avoided if they had followed those standards.

Answer (score 1):

At a previous job I worked we used Silverlight for precisely this type of purpose, we would send out SmartCards and SD cards with devices that recorded data onto them. Users would go to our website where we had an upload section which was a little Silverlight control that accessed the local SmartCard reader or drives looking for an SD card that had our folder structure. The Silverlight control would read the data and send it to a SOAP web service we had hosted in the website.

It was quite effective and easy to work with and maintain, if I had to access local devices again from a website I would definitely look at this approach.

Comment: I like this solution! I will run it by the team and if we choose it I will mark it as the answer...  Thanks!